# Why does this require "..path" is returning a fatal error (PHP)?

Tags: php, directory

my question is simple but I have not found a form to solve it. I am trying to include a library located on the magento's module which I am developing.

```
$simple_excel_path = Mage::getBaseDir('code')."/local/Javi/libraries/SimpleExcelLibrary/src/SimpleExcel/SimpleExcel.php";
echo $simple_excel_path;
require $simple_excel_path;
```

This code returns the following error:

**(echo) this route is correct.**
/home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/app/code/local/Javi/libraries/SimpleExcelLibrary/src/SimpleExcel/SimpleExcel.php

**(error) but the require function is going to another site**
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/app/codelocal/Javi/libraries/SimpleExcelLibrary/src/SimpleExcel/SimpleExcel.php' (include_path='/home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/app/code/local:/home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/app/code/community:/home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/app/code/core:/home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/lib:.:/usr/share/php') in /home/javiertxu/Documentos/webs/magentoabc/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/massiveupdatingproducts/massiveupdatingproductsbackend.phtml on line 5

This is the directory:

[image]

What I should do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module name is lowercase, you should change **libraries** for **Libraries**, following module naming convention in Magento

Magento adds every code pool folder as include path, so you don't need to pass the full path (although that shouldn't throw any error), it is enough starting path from your module main folder ('Javi')

Last thing, be sure the file has the right permissions to be readable by webserver user

Comment: Thanks, I solved that before you answered, but you were right, I gave permission 777 to the library and it run.